# Why do greek characters in math mode sometimes look tilted in OneNote 2016?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

I noticed that MS OneNote 2016 displays greek characters differently, but I'm not sure when.
[image: image description]
Above, the *otherwise* case is written as `\delta(\vartheta_k - \vartheta _(k+1))`.
Why is one of the two theta in cursive?

<sub>I have written this Q&A to share my own insights, but would be interested if you have more information.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting shows that it depends on how soon you type the underscore (`_`).
If you type `\vartheta_k`, the symbol will be in one style and if you type `\vartheta _k` (mind the space), the character will be tilted/cursive.

[image]

Interestingly enough, this seems not to happen to other characters. I'm unsure whether it's *just* the greek symbols, but for example the element symbol `∈` written with `\in` does not have this feature.